# wxPython -- easier way to do custom events?

Tags: user-interface, events, optimization, event-handling, wxpython

In my project, I am using wxPython and have a number of custom events that have to be caught, usually when a variable changes.  So, here's how I have it set up:

```
- Event happens (inside a function), it sends a louie signal
- Event Handler catches all event louie signals and performs a func call
- Function call posts the event
- Binding from widget catches it
- Widget sends it to a function in the Event Handler for handling
```

That seems like an awful lot of runaround.  Shouldn't there be a way to simply catch a variable change in a binding and send it to a function?  My senses are telling me I'm going about this all wrong. Is there an easier way?

EDIT 1: Here is the minimal, runnable code for my setup, the louie dispatches are because of the threading:

```
import time
import threading
import wx
from wx.lib.newevent import NewEvent
from louie import dispatcher

customEvent, EVT_CUSTOM_TEST = NewEvent()

def eventFire(changeTo):
    global customEvent
    changerContainer = customEvent(changeTo=changeTo)
    wx.PostEvent(text, changerContainer)

def change(event):
    text.SetLabel(event.changeTo)

class customThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, verbose=None, **kwargs):
        super(customThread, self).__init__(group=group, target=target, name=name, verbose=verbose)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            if i == 5:
                dispatcher.send("CHANGE ME", changeTo="Changed Text")
            time.sleep(1)

dispatcher.connect(eventFire, "CHANGE ME")

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, title="test", size=(100,100))
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
text = wx.StaticText(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Tester")
frame.Center()
frame.Show()
text.Bind(EVT_CUSTOM_TEST, change)
newThread = customThread()
newThread.start()
app.MainLoop()
```

EDIT 2: Using wxPython 2.8.12.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Why not just call the function that the widget event handler calls directly from your custom event handler?

Comment: I thought of that but didn't try it because I figured it had to be caught by a bind first or Mainloop would throw errors as it does when you try to directly change things?  Is that not the case?

Comment: Unless you're getting these messages in a different thread, then I don't think it will be an issue. If you can provide a small runnable example that demonstrates the issue, it will be a lot easier to help. Also which wxPython version are you using and which OS?

Comment: It took some doing, but I got a minimal example up.  Editing now...

Comment: It's edited.  Keep in mind, in my actual code, these functions and classes are all over the place so I'm sending, for example, the text identifier through the event channels so that I can change it over in the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use threads in wxPython and just call a thread-safe method instead of using dispatcher. A thread-safe method is `wx.PostEvent` or `wx.CallAfter`. I like using pubsub to pass the data around. So instead of

```
dispatcher.send("CHANGE ME", changeTo="Changed Text")
```

I would just do something like

```
wx.CallAfter(Publisher().sendMessage, "msg_name", "Changed Text")
```

Then the method that pubsub is connected to will fire. So you can make a common method

```
def change(text):
    text.SetLabel(text)
```

And call that via pubsub. Here are some links:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Note that that article uses wxPython 2.8 and the pubsub API changed in 2.9+. So you might want to look at this too:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/